# Reset table row after successful ajax jquery done in laravel blade

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a purchase due list table in my laravel project. While clicking in a purchase id I want to show the purchase detail in a modal table using Ajax request and after successfully showing the result want to reset the modal table automatically. But in my code modal table is not automatically reset though I am using `$('#datatable').reset();`.

**Modal Table**

```
<table id="datatable" class="display compact table table-bordered">
<thead class="thead-light">
    <tr>
        <th>Item Name</th>
        <th>Qty</th>
        <th>Unit Price</th>
        <th>Total Amount</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="item-tbody">
</tbody>
```

**Ajax**

```
$(".purchase_invoice").click(function(event) {
var pi_id = $(this).attr('href');
var table = '';

$.ajax({
            url: "{{ url('purchase-invoice-detail') }}"  + "/" + pi_id,
            type: "get",
            success: function(response){

                $.each( response, function( key, data ) {
                    $.each( data, function( key, value ) {

                        $(".pi_no").html(value['purchases_id']);
                        $(".pi_date").html(value['updated_at']);

                    table += '<tr>';
                        table += '<td>';
                            table += value['name'];
                        table += '</td>';
                        table += '<td>';
                            table += value['quantity'];
                        table += '</td>';
                        table += '<td>';
                            table += value['unit_price'];
                        table += '</td>';
                        table += '<td>';
                            table += value['total_amount'];
                        table += '</td>';
                    table += '</tr>';
                    });
                });

                table += '<tr>';
                    table += '<td colspan="3">Net Payable Amount:';
                    table += '</td>';
                    table += '<td colspan="1">';
                        table += response[0][0]['net_payable_amount'];
                    table += '</td>';
                table += '</tr>';

                $('#item-tbody').append(table);

                $("#viewModal").modal('show');
                $('#datatable').reset();

            },
                error: function(response){
                alert('Error'+response);
            }
        });
});
```

Where is the problem? Anybody help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you should change `$('#datatable').reset();` to:

```
$('#item-tbody').html('');
```

or

```
document.getElementById("item-tbody").value = "";
```

Comment: .......solved.....just small change needed. use `$('#item-tbody').html('');` instead of `$('#datatable').html('');` before the `Ajax` start. Please edit your answer. Thanks a lot.